# Tesseract low resolution number detection improve accuracy

Tags: c#, image-processing, numbers, ocr, tesseract

I would like to ask for some insight/assistance on how I might improve my OCR accuracy. My target images are low resolution (screenshots) and I would very much prefer not to upscale them, as my program needs to perform fast.

I have 2 images. I see no apparent difference between them, however tesseract is having trouble with one.

image 1 image2

[image]
[image]

The first image is the issue, the result I am getting is: **251\n41\n31\n\n11\n11\n\n11\n**
As you can see, there is something wrong with how it's handling the spacing. There are 2x new lines when things start to go wrong.

Meanwhile, in the second image I get the expected result: **300\n60\n40\n\n1\n15\n15\n10\n6\n15\n**
These images were created through the following preprocessing steps:

```
image.Alpha(AlphaOption.Remove);
image.BlackThreshold(new Percentage(27));
image.Negate(); // Original image has white text on black background
```

I have limited tesseract's charset to only digits (01234567890-).
I have tried various segmentation modes (SparseText, SingleColumn, SingleBlock). I am running Tesseract 4.1. Do you guys have any pointers?

Or maybe you could tell me what resize algorithm is fast and good for OCR?

Comment: Even the second image has extra newline after 40. For resize, try [this function](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d)

Answer (score -1):

If you are having issues with Tesseract and are considering using a more robust library without the need for training, you can try using a commercial library such as Leadtools. With the [Leadtools OCR toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr), I was able to get perfect results for both images with only the basic image processing built in to the OCR demo. There are, however, more sophisticated image processing functions that you can use for more complex tasks if need be. Besides the OCR demo, I was also able to get the same results, in JSON form, without any preprocessing, from one of the tutorials posted here below. As a disclaimer, I work for this vendor.

https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/dotnet-console-export-ocr-results-to-json.html

Here's some simplified source code that would achieve the same task for one image and print out the raw text:

```
// Create a new OCR engine with the default settings
IOcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD);
ocrEngine.Startup(null, null, null, null);

// Create an OCR document to hold everything
using (IOcrDocument ocrDocument = ocrEngine.DocumentManager.CreateDocument()){
    // Add the input image as a new page
    using(IOcrPage page = ocrDocument.Pages.AddPage(inputFilename, null)){
        // Perform OCR on just the one page
        page.Recognize(null);
        
        // build a string from the recognized characters
        string text = page.GetText(0);
        
        // Show output
        Console.WriteLine($"text: '{text}'");
    }   
}
```

The results I got for the two images were "251\r\n41\r\n31\r\n1\r\n11\r\n11\r\n7\r\n4\r\n11\r\n" and "300\r\n60\r\n40\r\n1\r\n15\r\n15\r\n10\r\n6\r\n15\r\n".